# Включить html/css/js в exe программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть компонент webbrowser и в него загружаются html/css/js, но загружаться через чтения файла и вставку данных в браузер.
Получается так, что вместе с файлом exe лежит еще куча файлов картинок, html, css и т.д.

Есть ли возможность включить их все в один файл?

Если с картинками все ясно - использовать файлы ресурсов, то с html/css/js нет.
Проблема состоит в тому, что на этапе разработки программы эти файлы нужно редактировать, а как редактировать файл ресурса, например формата js, через VS 2013 я не знаю.
Есть вариант не сохранять подобные файлы в файлах. То есть вместо

```
component.text = ReadAllFile(filename);
```

использовать

```
 component.text = "<h2>test</h2>";
```

Но файлы достаточно большие и засорять ими код на шарпе я не хочу.

Answer (score 1):

В MSDN есть [статья Embedding a JavaScript File as a Resource in an Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398930.aspx), посвящённая как раз этому вопросу. Хотя там используется старая студия, в качестве примера, в новой никаких существенных изменений производит не нужно. Что нужно:

1. Добавить требуемый файл в проект.
2. Изменить его тип на ресурсный.
3. В коде использовать его как ресурс, тогда как в проекте он будет доступен для редактирования как любой другой файл.